# how do i get an array of files using job dsl when triggered by a jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

how do i get an array of files using jenkins job-dsl when triggered by a jenkins-pipeline job ?
There is a single file option called readFileFromWorkspace but it doesn't help when i want the contents of a directory.

this needs to work on a slave rather than a master which rules out:

using this variable
`hudson.FilePath workspace = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor().getCurrentWorkspace()`
works when not using jenkins pipeline but errors out when you are

The environment variable WORKSPACE does not exist when using jenkins pipeline from what i can see

this format only works if you are running on the master 
`new File(__FILE__).parent.absolutePath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SEED_JOB` variable ([wiki](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands#seed-job)) to get the job which runs the Job DSL build step. In case of Pipeline, this should be a `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob`. And with `SEED_JOB.lastBuild` you should get the running build which is a `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun`. I do not know the Pipeline internals, but maybe you can look through the sources starting [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun.java).